# system.ExtrinsicFailed in Polkadot-JS

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, substrate-node-template, substrate-kitties-chain

I am following this tutorial : https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt1/#build-run-and-interact-with-your-kitties and completed the first part.
But on the polkadot.js, First I created kitties and if I wants to transfer these kitties then this error is shown : system.ExtrinsicFailed Substratekitties.kittyNotExist ->[image]

Comment: Can you share your repo pls. Its hard to know your problem from your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the sender doesn't have a kitty with the that Kitty Id. Confirm that you selected the right account (for the sender) and the right kitty Id.